# TimePreference not giving current values

Tags: android

I'm trying to get values from a custom TimePreference. After the mHour and mMinute variables are set, I get them in onPreferenceChange in PreferenceFragment.java.

Sorry for the wall of code, but I wanted to give everything for context. I believe my problem is occurring in TimePreference.onTimeChanged if you would like to focus there.

The problem I'm having is that I get the time I set previously whenever I get the values that were set in TimePreference.onTimeChanged. For example, if the clock is currently set to 1:00pm, and I change the time to 3:15pm, it will read out 13:00 instead of 15:15.

PreferenceFragment.java

```
 TimePreference timePicker = (TimePreference) findPreference("time");

    timePicker.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            TimePreference timePreference = (TimePreference) preference;

            Long hour = timePreference.getHour();
            Long minutes = timePreference.getMinutes();

            Log.d(TAG, hour + " " + minutes);

            parent.setHour(hour);
            parent.setMinutes(minutes);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

TimePreference.java:

```
public class TimePreference extends DialogPreference implements TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener {
    private Calendar mCalendar;
    private TimePicker picker = null;
    private long mHour;
    private long mMinutes;

    public TimePreference(Context ctxt) {
        this(ctxt, null);
    }

    public TimePreference(Context ctxt, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(ctxt, attrs, android.R.attr.dialogPreferenceStyle);
    }

    public TimePreference(Context ctxt, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(ctxt, attrs, defStyle);

        setPositiveButtonText(R.string.set);
        setNegativeButtonText(R.string.cancel);
        mCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    }

    public long getHour() {
        return mHour;
    }

    public long getMinutes() {
        return mMinutes;
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {
        picker = new TimePicker(getContext());
        picker.setOnTimeChangedListener(this);
        return (picker);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindDialogView(View v) {
        super.onBindDialogView(v);
        picker.setCurrentHour(mCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        picker.setCurrentMinute(mCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);

        if (positiveResult) {
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, picker.getCurrentHour());
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, picker.getCurrentMinute());

            setSummary(getSummary());
            if (callChangeListener(mCalendar.getTimeInMillis())) {
                persistLong(mCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
                notifyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray a, int index) {
        return (a.getString(index));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restoreValue, Object defaultValue) {
        if (restoreValue) {
            long persistedValue;
            try {
                persistedValue = getPersistedLong(System.currentTimeMillis());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //Stale persisted data may be the wrong type
                persistedValue = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            mCalendar.setTimeInMillis(persistedValue);
        } else if (defaultValue != null) {
            mCalendar.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong((String) defaultValue));
        } else {
            //!restoreValue, defaultValue == null
            mCalendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }

        setSummary(getSummary());
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getSummary() {
        if (mCalendar == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return DateFormat.getTimeFormat(getContext()).format(new Date(mCalendar.getTimeInMillis()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        mHour = hourOfDay;
        mMinutes = minute;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't sure but maybe your problem is you ignore the value that you received in OnPreferenceChangeListener , the  newValue object, and read the old objects.

Comment: you call `callChangeListener` before you persist the value. the value read in the listener is not yet updated, hence what you read.

Comment: njzk2, how would you suggest fixing it? I tried moving persistLong(...) above the if (callChangeListener(mCalendar.getTimeInMillis())) statement to no avail.